# Simple registration form not posting selected value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I am using Devexpress MVC extensions and trying to figure out a different issue by simplifying it as much as possible. According to the official site is should work, but the selection's value is not passed to the controller.

This is the model and the controller:

```
public class Fruit
   {
      public int value { get; set; }
      public string name { get; set; }
   }

public ActionResult Index()
      {
         var model = new object[1];
         var fruits = new List();

         fruits.Add(new Fruit() { value = 1, name = "Apple" });
         fruits.Add(new Fruit() { value = 2, name = "Orange"});
         fruits.Add(new Fruit() { value = 3, name = "Lemon"});
         fruits.Add(new Fruit() { value = 4, name = "Pear" });
         fruits.Add(new Fruit() { value = 5, name = "Cherry" });

         model[0] = fruits;
         return View(model);
      }
```

and the View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home"))
{
   @Html.DevExpress().FormLayout(settings =>
{
   settings.Name = "Myformlayout";
   settings.Width = 600;
   var gi = settings.Items.AddGroupItem(gs =>
   {
      gs.Caption = "TEST";
   });
   gi.Items.Add(item =>
   {
      item.Name = "fruits";
      item.Caption = "Fruits";
      item.NestedExtensionType = FormLayoutNestedExtensionItemType.ComboBox;
      ComboBoxSettings cbset = (ComboBoxSettings)item.NestedExtensionSettings;
      cbset.Properties.TextField = "name";
      cbset.Properties.ValueField = "value";
      cbset.Properties.ValueType = typeof(int);
      cbset.Properties.DropDownStyle = DropDownStyle.DropDownList;
      cbset.Properties.DataSource = Model[0];
   });

   gi.Items.Add(item =>
   {
      item.NestedExtensionType = FormLayoutNestedExtensionItemType.Button;
      var btnset = (ButtonSettings)item.NestedExtensionSettings;
      btnset.Name = "btnSubm";
      btnset.Text = "Send to ctrl";
      btnset.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
   });
}).GetHtml();
```

The selection is working fine, but when the "Send to ctrl" button is clicked I get a "The parameter dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id'. The controller "Home\Create" expects a int id parameter. If I change the parameter requirement of the controller to int?, the call is made, so the submit works.

**The goal**: send back to the controller the selected fruit's id(value).

Comment: From what I see, you do not have a field for ID on your view. Btw, how the Create action is implemented?

Comment: I am not implementing Create, just want to figure out how to pass the selected text's value. According tot the DevExpress demo, this should work, since this is how you define a dropdown list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gave me the answer: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument9151

So the controller looks like this:

```
  public ActionResult Create(MyModel item)
      {
         var x = EditorExtension.GetValue<int>("FruitId");

         return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }
```

Thank you for your help. Sorry I don't know whose answer lead me to the desired solution. Thumps up for you both!

Answer (score 1):

What do you need to achieve? To edit a field of your model by using a combobox? If so, I'd implement this in the following way:

Model:

```
public class MyModel {
    public int FruitId { get; set; }
    public MyModel() {

    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var fruits = new List<Fruit>();

    fruits.Add(new Fruit() { id = 0, name = "Apple" });
    fruits.Add(new Fruit() { id = 1, name = "Orange" });
    fruits.Add(new Fruit() { id = 2, name = "Lemon" });
    fruits.Add(new Fruit() { id = 3, name = "Pear" });
    fruits.Add(new Fruit() { id = 4, name = "Cherry" });

    ViewBag.FruitSource = fruits;
    return View(new MyModel());
}

public ActionResult Create(int fruitId) {
    return View(fruitId);
}

public class Fruit {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model DXWebApplication1.Models.MyModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home")) {
    @Html.DevExpress().FormLayout(settings => {
    settings.Name = "Myformlayout";
    settings.Width = 600;
    var gi = settings.Items.AddGroupItem(gs => {
        gs.Caption = "TEST";
    });
    gi.Items.Add(x => x.FruitId, item => {
        item.Caption = "Fruits";
        item.NestedExtensionType = FormLayoutNestedExtensionItemType.ComboBox;
        ComboBoxSettings cbset = (ComboBoxSettings)item.NestedExtensionSettings;
        cbset.Properties.TextField = "name";
        cbset.Properties.ValueField = "id";
        cbset.Properties.ValueType = typeof(int);
        cbset.Properties.DropDownStyle = DropDownStyle.DropDownList;
        cbset.Properties.DataSource = ViewBag.FruitSource;
    });

    gi.Items.Add(item => {
        item.NestedExtensionType = FormLayoutNestedExtensionItemType.Button;
        var btnset = (ButtonSettings)item.NestedExtensionSettings;
        btnset.Name = "btnSubm";
        btnset.Text = "Send to ctrl";
        btnset.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
    });
}).GetHtml();
}
```

So, I bind a layout item to my model property using Lambda. That field name (FruitId) will be the name of the Create action parameter.

Comment: Thank you Gosha, according to Murat's link, if the controller expecting a MyModel type object, then I can see the FruitId is 0, not null. It seems to me for some reason there is no binding with the submit button.

Comment: If your goal is to get a selected fruit id, my solution should work, should not it? Pleade elaborate

Comment: I've copied your solution into my project, and it gave me the exact error message as described in question. Also I think it is not related, but after every run I need to restart VS2015 because OutOfMemory exception occurs.